# How do i compute with (numpy) -arrays eloquently in python

Tags: python, loops

How can i express this construct in a more efficient way?

```
x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
for p in x:
   x = x/2
print x
```

there has to be a good way to do this.

Comment: Your code will raise a `TypeError`. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, can you try rephrasing the question or providing a valid code example?

Comment: hi maybe you express has some error, x=x/2, how a list can divide by a integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to divide every element of `x` by `2`, then the following will do it:

```
x = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
x /= 2
```

The resulting value of `x` is `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`.

Note that the above uses integer (truncating) division. If you want floating-point division, either make `x` into a floating-point array:

```
x = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10], dtype='float64')
```

or change the division to:

```
x = x / 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a numpy array You can do it all at once:

```
In [4]: from numpy import array

In [5]: x = array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

In [6]: print x/2
[1 2 3 4 5]
```